# How to change products per page based on media query value

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, css

I was wondering if their is a way to change the amount of products are shown on a page based on the media query? So say on mobile you could state that you only want one product, but on desktop you still want 18.

Thanks

Comment: well, you could have different theme folder for either desktop or mobile display, then instead of querying your products on a Block or Controller side, query them on your template files (which is not super clean, let's be honest). This way you'd have different queries and thus different amounts of products shown, if you so wished.

Answer (score 0):

If your html structure is something like that :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

You could use media queries mixed with the :nth-child selector to do that. I did it in a project by the following :

```
/* TABLET FORMAT */
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .item:nth-child(n+8){
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: the idea on mobile devices is not to hide data. The idea is not not load it at all. So only hiding elements, does not really solve the problem.

Comment: Just to make it clear. this should work, but it's not the best idea to take this approach.

Answer (score 0):

The items per page, come from the config.
So maybe it would be a good idea to change the config value at runtime (only for the current page, not for all users) and fill in the values you want:

```
$code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
$config = Mage::getConfig();
$config->setNode("stores/$code/catalog/frontend/list_per_page_values", '1,2,4'); //set the allowed number of products per page
$config->setNode("stores/$code/catalog/frontend/list_per_page", '1'); //set the default number of products per page.
```

You can use an early event to do this. You need an event dispatched after the store is determined, but before the page is displayed.

You can use this one for the category page `controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view` and this for the search results `controller_action_predispatch_catalogsearch_result_index`.
If you don't want to observe multiple events you can just use `controller_action_predispatch`.

the observer should look something like this

```
public function setPerPage($observer)
{
    if (on mobile device) {
         //the code from above
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Marius, I would like to test out the above. But I not sure where I should put the above suggested code in.

Comment: Here is an explanation on how to create an observer for an event: https://www.ashsmith.io/2012/12/making-use-of-observers-in-magento/. I listed above the events you can use and the code that should go in the observer. the only thing you need to figure out is "if (on mobile device)".